# Finding length of side in isosceles triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

knowing the angle alpha and the height inside an isosceles triangle, how can I get the length of the side y?

[isosceles triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEBtb.png)

I did search in search engines for the formula for too long but could not find it and I cant remember a lot from trigonoetry from school and how to derive this. So I thought I ask here ... thanks for understanding and any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the relation $$\tan(\alpha/2)=\frac{\frac{y}{2}}{h}$$

Answer (score 0):

Construct the perpendicular bisector of the base side.  This cuts the triangle into two right triangles.  Take one of them.

This triangle has sides:  $h$ = height of the triangle; $\frac y2$ = half of the side opposite $\alpha$ (the side that *isn't* equal in the isoceles triangle); and $x$ = the side that is equal in the isoceles triangle.

The angles of the right triangle are: $\frac {\alpha }2$; $90$, $90-\frac {\alpha}2$.

$\sin \frac \alpha 2= \frac {\frac y2}s$

$\cos \frac \alpha 2 = \frac hs$

$\tan \frac \alpha 2 = \frac {\frac y2}h= \frac y{2h}$.

And so $y = 2h*\tan \frac \alpha 2$.

(You can also find out the other two sides of the isoceles triangle this way:  $s = \frac h{\cos \frac\alpha 2}=h*\sec \frac \alpha 2$)